# How set RedirectAttributes in Controller Test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I need test my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(path="/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RedirectView addToCart(@ModelAttribute(value="productId") long productId, @ModelAttribute(value="quantity") int quantity, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws ProductNotFoundException {

  RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("/product/");
  redirect.setExposeModelAttributes(false);

  try {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", shoppingCartService.addQuantity(sCart, productId, quantity));
      } catch (ExceedsProductQuantityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flash", new FlashMessage(e.getMessage(),  FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
      }

  return redirect;
}
```

My test code looks like:

```
@Test(expected = ExceedsProductQuantityException.class)
public void addTooManyToCartTest1() throws Exception {
    Product product = productBuilder();
    product.setQuantity(15);

    Purchase purchase = purchaseBuilder(product); // First purchase

    when(productService.findById(1L)).thenReturn(product);
    when(sCart.getPurchase()).thenReturn(purchase);

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/cart/add")
        .param("quantity", String.valueOf(product.getQuantity() + 1))
        .param("productId", "1"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attribute("flash", "rdValue"))
        .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.flash().attribute("flash", FlashMessage.class));
}
```

But I get NestedServledException error message, I think its because in my controller method I try to work with RedirectedAttributes, but it's null. So, where and how I have to init and set RedirectedAttributes in my test?

Answer (score 0):

Problem wasnt in RedirectAttributes, there was sCart Mock uninitialized.
I believe you dont need give RedirectAttributes with request as other params.